# Variable in recursive function keeps it value

Tags: c#, php, recursion, static, static-variables

I am trying to convert this php code to C# code.

Let say we have some matrix of numbers

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

This php code finds how many combinations can be if we can only for one step in any directions, without repeating ourself.
From number 1 it can be for example:

```
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,6
1,2,3,5,9
```

... and etc.

This php code works fine, but when I do the same in C# result as different, and at the end I receive error.

I found the problem with varible `path`. In recursion it stores its value when going depth.

How can I solve this problem? I know there is something with static variable issue, but cannot find out.

```php
<?php 
$paths = array();

function find_path($graph, $start, $end, $path = array())
{
  global $paths;
  $path[] = $start;

  if ($start == $end)
     return $path;

  if (!isset($graph[$start]))
     return false;

  foreach($graph[$start] as $node) {
    if (!in_array($node, $path)) {
      $newpath = find_path($graph, $node, $end, $path);
      if ($newpath) 
        $paths[] = implode(',', $newpath);
    }
  }
  return array();
}
$graph = array(
  '1' => array('2', '4', '5'),
  '2' => array('1', '3', '5', '4', '6'),
  '3' => array('2', '5', '6'),
  '4' => array('1', '2', '7', '8', '5'),
  '5' => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8'),
  '6' => array('3', '2', '5', '9', '8'),
  '7' => array('4', '5', '8'),
  '8' => array('4', '6', '6', '7', '9'),
  '9' => array('5', '6', '8')
);
for($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++)  
  for($j = 1; $j <= 9; $j++)
    find_path($graph, (string) $i, (string) $j);
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace ConsoleSlovoMania
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<string> newpath = new List<string>();

        static void Main()
        {
            int[][] graph = new int[10][];

            graph[1] = new int[] { 2, 4, 5 };
            graph[2] = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 4, 6 };
            graph[3] = new int[] { 2, 5, 6 };
            graph[4] = new int[] { 1, 2, 7, 8, 5 };
            graph[5] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
            graph[6] = new int[] { 3, 2, 5, 9, 8 };
            graph[7] = new int[] { 4, 5, 8};
            graph[8] = new int[] { 4, 6, 6, 7, 9};
            graph[9] = new int[] { 5, 6, 8 };

            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) 
                {
                    find_path(graph, i, j);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<string> find_path(int[][] graph, int start, int end, List<string> path = null)
        {

            Console.Write("start = " + start + " | end = " + end);
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (path == null)
            {
                path = new List<string>();
            }
            path.Add(start.ToString());
            path.ForEach(Console.Write);
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (start == end)
            {
                return path;
            }

            foreach (int node in graph[start])
            {
                if (path.Exists(element => element == node.ToString()) == false)
                {
                    newpath.AddRange(find_path(graph, node, end, path));
                    if (newpath.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //newpath.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                        newpath.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            return path = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think find_path is a static function you should use Program.find_path(args)

Comment: What error do you receive? And just put breakpoints and start debugging.

Comment: @CodeCaster problem is not an error itself, but logic of recursion. Variable 'path' holds its value after recursion function return value.

Comment: @user3510665 I tried, result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the exception:

`newpath.AddRange()` throws an exception when `find_path()` returns null.

Assign result of `find_path()` to a variable and check for null before adding to `newpath`

To fix the logic error, remember that in .NET `List<String>` is an object, and when you pass `path` in the recursive step you are passing the value of the reference to that object, not a copy of the object. Easy fix: just copy the list (easy with LINQ), like this:

`path.ToList()`

Here is the complete fixed C# code. I rearranged it and renamed a couple variables to be a more 1:1 transliteration of the PHP code; it made it easier to find and fix the `List<String> path` mutation issue.

```
namespace ConsoleSlovoMania
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<string> paths = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> find_path(int[][] graph, int start, int end, List<string> path = null)
        {
            if (path == null)
            {
                path = new List<string>();
            }
            path.Add(start.ToString());
            if (start == end)
            {
                return path;
            }
            foreach (int node in graph[start])
            {
                if (!path.Contains(node.ToString()))
                {
                    // before calling recursive step, copy path instead of passing around object reference value
                    List<String> newPath = find_path(graph, node, end, path.ToList());
                    if (newPath != null)
                    {
                        paths.Add(String.Join(",", newPath.ToArray()));
                    }
                }
            }
            return path = null;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int[][] graph = new int[10][];
            graph[1] = new int[] { 2, 4, 5 };
            graph[2] = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 4, 6 };
            graph[3] = new int[] { 2, 5, 6 };
            graph[4] = new int[] { 1, 2, 7, 8, 5 };
            graph[5] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
            graph[6] = new int[] { 3, 2, 5, 9, 8 };
            graph[7] = new int[] { 4, 5, 8};
            graph[8] = new int[] { 4, 6, 6, 7, 9};
            graph[9] = new int[] { 5, 6, 8 };

            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) 
                {
                    find_path(graph, i, j);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

To verify results, you could put a breakpoint on the line with `Console.ReadyKey()` and verify that the contents of `paths` is equivalent to the result returned by the PHP code. For PHP you could use a debugger, or `print_r($paths)` to spit out the array. I automated this validation by serializing `paths` and `$paths` to JSON which was super easy to test in jsFiddle, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ea89L8x8/

Comment: That fixed error, thanks. But what about variable 'path' which stores information after being in recursion function?

Comment: Oh, forgot to add the testing code: `echo json_encode($paths, 128);` for PHP JSON, and `String json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(paths)` (requires `System.Web.Extensions` reference, I believe)